# call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in codeigniter in cli command

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

**Fatal Error** call to undefined function `mysqli_connect()` in code igniter database driver when the controller is called through **CLI** i.e by command php `index.php` controller.

If i run controller not by **CLI** it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has different configuration for CLI and web (like from Apache or NGinx).  You need to check your config and make sure MySQLi is enabled for CLI.

Comment: which config file you are talking about?

Comment: Php.ini - if you have multiple versions of php installed on your machine, Apache might be configured with one, and your command prompt might default to the other.

Comment: I think i found the issue my Cli is using the php version 7 but when i check php info in browser it shows me the version 5.6